# How to Debug the asp.net web application without disturbing the release build?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I'm working asp.net web based application, I have deployed this application on server, Its getting response on port 80 from a outside client. 
I want the to fix the bugs so I want to run this application in Debug mode so that I can attach the worker process with the application and this is making the Performance down and its disturbing the QA team. 
So can I have two application one can run in release mode so that QA activity does not get disturbed and parallelly I can debug the build and fix the bugs or can do further development.
I'm facing the same problem during the development activity, If multiple developers are working paralley , only one is able to debug the application other one has to wait.
So please suggest me, If I can get rid of this situation.

I have only one server on which I can test this application.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way too long discussion, but I will try to offer you a few ideas:

1. Each developer should develop on his own machine (sources and database should be local).
2. In order to sync your work you should use:
   a. a source control solution like TFS or SVN (this is free) for your sources. 
   b. database changes can easily be synced by generating update scripts using SQL Schema Compare directly from Visual Studio (you will need SQL Server Data Tools for this), Redgate SQL Compare or another application that can compare the database strucure (there are many available online, some of them free).
3. You should have a separate server (DB and app) to testing.
4. You should have a separate server (DB anb app) for production.

You say you have one server to test the application. But I suppose each developer has his own computer, right? In this case you need to skip #3 and use the same server for testing and production, but with different databases and applications.

I suggest you check this website for similar answers (see [Best practice for test and production environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285731/best-practice-for-test-and-production-environments) for example) to find the best solution that applies in your case.

Comment: But I can not hit the outside URL from my local machine due to some access rights, this can be done only from the server machine.

Comment: Why do you need to hit the external URL? You should try to replicate all the reported bugs in your developer environment and fix them there.

Comment: because Its my project requirement.

Comment: Your requirement is to have the application and database installed only on the production server?

Comment: @VivekJain - you can use your host file to tell your local computer to redirect the outside url to your local machine (from requests on your local machine).  This makes it seem like you're hitting the outside url, but you're really hitting your local computer and not disturbing the production server.